# Is there a way to use Azure Diagnostics 1.0 for Azure SDK 2.5 projects

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

Is there a way to keep Diagnostics 1.0 but upgrade to Azure SDK 2.5?

We use very simple diagnostics that just writes into Trace (and as a result into storage table). We also deploy our service as a package via Azure portal. Introducing of Diagnostics 1.3 is a quite a breaking change for our process, since it requires PowerShell to deploy Diagnostics extension.

I tried to revert back Cloud configuration files (import Diagnostics module) but it is not working. It seems that I have to stay on SDK 2.4 for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to keep Diagnostics 1.0 but upgrade to Azure SDK 2.5?

Unfortunately No. If you upgrade your Cloud Services to SDK 2.5, you can't use diagnostics 1.0. You have to use 1.3 version of the diagnostics.

We did the same with our projects and faced more or less the same issues as you faced and had to revert back. What we did was kept SDK 2.5 installed on the machines however our projects still use SDK 2.4 i.e. all referenced libraries in our project are from SDK 2.4.